# Tilesets in Android

Tags: android, tiles

I have been trying to use a Tileset in a game I am making on an Android phone, however the image always comes out wrong, when not used on the exactly right density/size phone.
I suspect the compile process, or the folder used in res in eclipse, is effecting it somehow, does anyne have any experience in this?
 (Edited because missed part out last time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you accessing your tilesets? If you are grabbing them from your assets folder you will need to figure out which ones to use on your own.

If you can, just placing them in the proper dpi folders will probably make it easier.